# Can't get Debian Live running on a Lenovo Ideapad S145

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I recently acquired a brand new Lenovo Ideapad S145 and was exciting to have the newest Debian version working on it.

But I can't get Debian 10.10 Live USB running after the very first screen on choosing to run Debian Live.

I already searched a lot but doesn't find anything to help me. The only errors I see is on the picture I got from the screen after select Debian Live to run.

[image]

After these errors, the screen display only a blinking prompt at the top left corner.

Anyone there with problems installing Debian 10 (I'm trying 10.10) on a Lenovo Ideapad S145?

Comment: have you disabled uefi? it may have secure boot enabled.

Comment: Intels iwlwifi firmware is missing as it's non-free software, but I don't know if this is causing the system to hang. Probably not.
I'd try one of the [debian-live-bullseye-RC2+nonfree](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/bullseye_di_rc2-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/) images which include [firmware-iwlwifi](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-iwlwifi) and come with a more recent 5.10 kernel.

Comment: Do you have Windows installed on the Ideapad S145?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I disabled the UEFI and the UEFI error is gone. But the next screen, after the initial warnings, including the iwlwifi, is not rendered. So I suspect now the problem is with the video driver. Thanks @Freddy for the tip for nonfree image. I will try Debian Live with this nonfree image to see if the issue with the video driver is solved. And Cinaed, I don't have Windows installed. I have Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: You got it @Freddy. The Bullseye RC2 nonfree ISO Live with 5.10 kernel runs very well and recognizes wifi as well as video, other firmware I was having issues.