# Debian 10.10 non-free iso Live Pen Drive can't go live in a Lenovo Ideapad s145 81S9000RBR

Tags: debian, drivers, video, live-usb, firmware

I'm struggling with running a Live USB Pen Drive with Debian 10.10 non-free iso in my Lenovo Ideapad S145. But trying with or without UEFI support can't start the system. It stays halted on a black screen. I think this is probably because of lack of the video driver in the Live CD, but I'm not sure of.

Follow are the screens that maybe can help to find out why.

**BIOS Boot Configuration**:
[image: BIOS Boot Configuration]

**Selecting Debian Live**:
[image: Selecting Debian Live]

**The last message before enter into black screen**:
[image: The last screen before black]

So that was the screen info.

Now, what I could extract from my current Ubuntu 20.20 installation about the video driver firmware.

`lspci -v`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a56 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
  Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3fdc
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 152
  Memory at 94000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
  Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
  I/O ports at 5000 [size=64]
  Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
  Capabilities: <access denied>
  Kernel driver in use: i915
  Kernel modules: i915
```

`lshw -c video`:

```
*-display                 
       descrição: VGA compatible controller
       produto: Intel Corporation
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       ID físico: 2
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:00:02.0
       versão: 07
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuração: driver=i915 latency=0
       recursos: irq:152 memória:94000000-94ffffff memória:80000000-8fffffff porta de E/S:5000(tamanho=64) memória:c0000-dffff
```

`modinfo i915`:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.8.0-63-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
```

From `modinfo i915` output, we can see that the current video driver has a `GPL and additional` rights license.

By all the output I posted here it seems is a problem with the i915 Intel driver. Could it be for another reason? Is there a way of running Debian 10.10 Live USB, or I will have to install Debian first without video support, and after that try to install the video driver?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I already deleted the other one.

Comment: Have you tried Debian bullseye (as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657591/cant-get-debian-live-running-on-a-lenovo-ideapad-s145#comment1237726_657591))?

According to [Lenovo](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/de/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/ideapad-s-series-netbooks/s145-15iwl/81s9/81s9000rbr) it's an 8th gen. i5-8265U, UHD Graphics 620?

Comment: You got it @Freddy. The Bullseye RC2 nonfree ISO Live with 5.10 kernel runs very well and the firmwares for both wifi and video looks like working very good. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please write that up as an answer, you can accept it later. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thank you!